# How to install Chosen using Drush Make?

Tags: installation, drush, theming

From [Chosen](http://drupal.org/project/chosen) module page:

> This module comes with a Drush make file, which will automatically download the jQuery plugin if you use Drush make to set up your website.

I have Drush Make, but commands like..

```
 drush dl chosen
 drush en chosen
```

..don't help.
Should I use `drush make ...` command instead? Maybe there are other commands for quick libraries download.

P.S. I'm working on already installed copy of Drupal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way:

```
# cd to Drupal root folder
drush dl chosen
drush make sites/all/modules/chosen/chosen.make.example --no-core
drush en chosen -y
```

**Update 04/29/2014**: Chosen now provides Drush command `chosenplugin`.

This answer is still useful for other projects with `*.make.example` files but without custom Drush installation commands.

Answer (score 3):

for the latest version of chosen I usually do the following

drush dl chosen

drush chosenplugin

drush en chosen -y

You not only need to download the drupal module (drush dl chosen) but also the chosen jQuery library (drush chosenplugin) in order for the module to work.

Comment: Thanks @Jen for your answer! Good to know. For projects with Drush Make files (usually `modulename.make.example`) but without custom Drush commands (like `chosenplugin` or `colorbox-plugin`) it is still possible to download external libraries and other dependencies with trick in my answer.